# how to discover devices in a large heterogenous network with huawei, cisco, alcatel and more different devices without using snmp?

Tags: cisco, fortigate, network-discovery, automation, huawei

i have a huge task to do and i need your help.I am new to the whole networking world and I apologize if this is a re-post of a question.
so what i wanted is to discover and mapping all my enterprise network on a web app using network standard commands and protocol but not using snmp. I have a huge network with devices from many vendor such as huawei NE40, Cicco, Juniper, fortinet ...

I directed this question to you experts cause i do not have the knowledge or know the keywords to search online on this subject matter.

Comment: Sounds like you want to screw without a screwdriver...

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there are several software solutions available that will map out the network topology.

Comment: @JohnK. is there some that are multi-vendor and don't rely on SNMP? (nor LLDP since it's not enabled as stated in a comment on Zac67 answer).

Comment: I don't actually see a question anywhere in your post. Question are sentences that end with question marks (`?`). If you are looking for a product or resource recommendation, those are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: OK. I am looking for an approach because i wanted to developp my own network discovery tools or start from an existing open source solution that i could customized for my company

Comment: ok but why ruling out SNMP? By doing so your render the task so much more difficult.

Comment: I don't have SNMP credentials. I am asking to my boss he tell me that snmp is not at all secure and all devices of the network did'nt support SNMP. i am just an intern in my company. i have to search an alternative for do this job.

Comment: if i could use snmp how could i use it to discover all my network from my computer?

Comment: @billz_the_king I think NetBrain can.  I think you can get a free trial.

Comment: I already try netbrain... it's a very powerfull tool. but what i want is to create my own tool.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what layer you want to/can discover devices. At the link layer, LLDP comes to mind but it requires you to directly interface with the device and only gives just a few items.

In a layer 2 network, you can scan for MAC/IP addresses by ARP. The vendor specific part (OUI) of the MAC tells you the vendor. Reverse DNS possibly tells you the device name.

When it comes to applications, it gets hard. You'd need to do a port scan which takes quite a while and only tells you on which ports a device accepts connections. Port probing might reveal what is behind a port but requires to know what you're looking for.

SNMP is a standardized protocol for exactly this purpose and it allows you to efficiently collect a wide range of information. If you want to collect detailed info without SNMP you'd probably need to do it manually (ie. look at each config).

Comment: i use telnet to interface with  the devices and CDP to sh their neighbours. it'is walk good only in the cisco devices.  LLDP is not enable on my network. i am working on link layer! how could i work do use only one approach for all kind on devices?

Comment: LLDP on the link layer (very limited data) and SNMP on L3 are probably the only non-proprietary choices you have.